# I can't create a long linked list

Tags: go

```
package main

func main() {
    var arr [99]ListNode
    for i := 0; i < 99; i++ {
        var tempArr ListNode
        tempArr.Val = i
        arr[i] = tempArr
    }
    for i := 0; i < 98; i++ {
        arr[i].Next = &arr[i+1]
    }
}

type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}
```

I want to create a linked list with 99 elements, but it breaks every 3 node. See the image below for more information:

[image]

Comment: Even though that is not the way to create a linked list, what you have written is working fine.It is creating a linked list of 98 values. Here is the [code](https://play.golang.org/p/qc7Bi7kl2Ck) to check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linked list is working fine although it's not the right way to create linked lists. The reason that you only 3 nodes is your debugger tracing limitations. I wrote a printing loop to show the values in the linked list.

```
package main

func main() {
    var arr [99]ListNode
    for i := 0; i < 99; i++ {
        var tempArr ListNode
        tempArr.Val = i
        arr[i] = tempArr
    }
    for i := 0; i < 98; i++ {
        arr[i].Next = &arr[i+1]
    }
}

type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}
```

Also I wrote another code to show how you can create linked lists in its proper way.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    start := &ListNode{}
    node := start
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        node.Val = i
        node.Next = &ListNode{}
        node = node.Next
    }
    for node := start; node.Next != nil; node = node.Next {
        fmt.Printf("%d -> ", node.Val)
    }
}

type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I get it. Now, I use IntelliJ IDEA for my golang leaning, which IDE is ok for this problem?

Comment: The issue could be not from the IDE because almost every IDE uses [delv](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) as the debugger. Though if you want to try another IDE give it shot. Try atom for example it's awesome.

Comment: Also, get use to printing everything everywhere for debugging instead of using a debugger in my experience it's the most effective approach. because there are environments it's hard to setup a debugger or the debugger performance is awful. e.g. having the binary running on a remote machine or having an embedded board running the program (which is the debugging is done through [JTAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG)).